# BeautifulSoup - lxml and html5lib parsers scraping differences

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml, html5lib

I am using **BeautifulSoup 4** with **Python 2.7**. I would like to extract certain elements from a website (Quantities, see the example bellow). For some reason, the **lxml** parser doesn't allow me to extract all of the desired elements from the page. It would print the first three elements only. I am trying to use the **html5lib** parser to see if I can extract all of them.

The page contains multiple items, with their price and quantities. A portion of the code containing the desired information for each of the item looks like this:

```
<td class="size-price last first" colspan="4">
                    <span>453 grams </span>
            <span> <span class="strike">$619.06</span> <span class="price">$523.91</span>
                    </span>
                </td>
```

Let's consider the following three cases:

**CASE 1 - DATA:**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
<td class="size-price last first" colspan="4">
                    <span>453 grams </span>
            <span> <span class="strike">$619.06</span> <span class="price">$523.91</span>
                    </span>
                </td>"""                
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup.td.span.text
```

Prints:

```
453 grams
```

**CASE 2 - LXML:**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
webpage = urlopen('The URL goes here')
soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
print soup.find('td', {'class': 'size-price'}).span.text
```

Prints:

```
453 grams
```

**CASE 3 - HTML5LIB:**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen
webpage = urlopen('The URL goes here')
soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html5lib")
print soup.find('td', {'class': 'size-price'}).span.text
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dom\Python-Code\src\Testing-Code.py", line 6, in <module>
    print soup.find('td', {'class': 'size-price'}).span.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

How do I have to adapt my code in order to extract the information that I want using the html5lib parser? I can see all of the desired information if I simply print the soup in the console after using the html5lib, so I figured it would allow me to get what I want. It is not the case for the lxml parser so I am also curious about the fact that the lxml parser doesn't seem to extract all of the Quantities using the lxml parser if I use:

```
print [td.span.text for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'size-price'})]
```

Comment: `html5lib` omits the `td` tag and puts everything inside the html body - this is because there is no `table` tag around the `td` and `html5lib` is concerned about it.

Comment: Interesting, so now how should I proceed in order to extract the elements that I want using html5lib

Comment: Well, why do you want to use `html5lib`? FYI, you can also make use of `html.parser`, e.g.: `BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')`.

Comment: RuntimeWarning: Python's built-in HTMLParser cannot parse the given document. This is not a bug in Beautiful Soup. The best solution is to install an external parser (lxml or html5lib), and use Beautiful Soup with that parser. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser for help.
`"Python's built-in HTMLParser cannot parse the given document. This is not a bug in Beautiful Soup. The best solution is to install an external parser (lxml or html5lib), and use Beautiful Soup with that parser.`

Comment: Gotcha :) Can I see the whole html document (or link) you are trying to parse?

Comment: I'd rather keep it private if you don't mind. I know it can't really help you much if I don't give you the specific URL... Let's say I use REGEX to compile the prices, 
`soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")
FindPrice = re.compile('\$\d+\.\d{2}')
print re.findall(FindPrice, str(soup))`
It won't print all of the prices on the page. Using html5lib will.
Same thing with the quanitities. This is why I want to use html5lib. I'm just looking for a way to use BeautifulSoup with html5lib like I do with lxml since scraping with REGEX isn't recommended...

Answer (score 0):

```
from lxml import etree

html = 'your html'
tree = etree.HTML(html)
tds = tree.xpath('.//td[@class="size-price last first"]')
for td in tds:
    price = td.xpath('.//span[@class="price"]')[0].text
    strike = td.xpath('.//span[@class="strike"]')[0].text
    spans = td.xpath('.//span')
    quantity = [i.text for i in spans if 'grams' in i.text][0].strip(' ')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    data = """
    <td class="size-price last first" colspan="4">
                <span>453 grams </span>
        <span> <span class="strike">$619.06</span> <span 
    class="price">$523.91</span>
                </span>
            </td>"""                
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
    print text
```